# Angular js edit page view

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs 1 this is my response

```
<table class="table myCustomTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in data | filter: searchKeyword">
    <td><a href="#/user/{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{user.emaik}}</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Response comming fine but I don't know how to create and redirect to edit page view

Also I want to get all details in edit page view

I don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS using routing you can traverse from one page to another . Easiest way to achieve it by Route provider - `$route` or by State provider - `$state`. 
And by using `$routeParams` or `$stateParams` you can pass parameters from one page to another.

Comment: for template how i use

Comment: You can use ui boostrap modal or any other popup to open template.
To change the view try [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)